# What's the easiest code signing certificate to get?

Tags: code-signing

We tried to get a code signing certificate for an application. The only business address is the owners home address, and a few other complications that were becoming difficult to satisfy Comodo. We also have a PO box, but that was not acceptable to use on the white page listings that they required we have. Does anyone know of a code signing company that doesn't require so many things to be arranged this way?

Comment: That is the whole point of one of these certificates - it authenticates you. If the cert company cannot tick all the boxes, then you cannot be adequately authenticated. It's not a process that should be shortcut. If anybody could get these with minimal effort then certs would be worthless as a trust mechanism.

Comment: I understand but for example, we have our bank registered to our accountants address. We had the bank manager stamp+sign a copy of a statement with the owners home address. They said they would accept it only as verification of the accountants address. They refused to call the bank to verify the other address. If this is for security, I could have easily forged the document with a different address. I understand the need for verification and i'm happy to comply, i'm just looking for a company that's not so lazy in connecting the dots.

Comment: Can I suggest you change the wording of your question then? There is a big difference between seeking an "easy" certificate and avoiding a company that's lazy. And keep in mind that asking for recommendations is off topic.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on who your users are, you could go with a self-signed certificate.  They're free and don't require an address.  The down-side is that browsers will display a warning that the certificate is not trusted.

If that creates a problem for you, then you'll probably have to provide a physical address.  All of the signing authorities I'm aware of require one.